# Check if a Range in Datagridview contains an "," if yes change it to ":"

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

My application contains a Datagridview, the user has the possibility to enter values like: Day, Time, how many hours did he work etc. The problem is that my second application calculates with this data. It has to be in a certain format.
Like time should be "09:15", but i noticed that some users are using "09,15" instead. Can you help me guys, I need a code that can check if a Range in Datagridview contains some " blacklisted char" and if yes, replaces it with the right one.
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not save values as a string.
Validate input string straight in the needed type.
Then validated values pass to the second application.
In this case you don't need "blacklisted chars"

```
Private Sub DataGridView_CellValidating(sender As Object, 
                                        e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs)
    If e.RowIndex < 0 Then Exit sub
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim columnIndexWithInteger As Integer = 2
    Dim columnIndexWithDate As Integer = 3

    Select Case e.ColumnIndex
        Case columnIndexWithInteger 
            Dim temp As Integer
            If Integer.TryParse(e.FormattedValue, temp) = False Then
                e.Cancel = True
            End If

        Case columnIndexWithDate 
            Dim temp As Date
            If Date.TryParse(e.FormattedValue, temp) = False Then
                e.Cancel = True
            End If

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to use it in a certain Range, cause there are more cells that use normal text input as Name etc... 
I dont know why but as I select an cell and give a value I cant press any other buttons inside the app, I have to close it in the editor...

Comment: You cannot move to another control or cell because validating failed. Press `Esc` or input a valid value. By column index you can access any range you want

Answer (score 0):

In `DataGridView`, you have one handle that allows you to check the validity of an edited cell : [`CellValueValidating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating(v=vs.110).aspx). It is called before the user change is taken into account (`CellValueChanged` event).

You can find example and explanation here :
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykdxa0bc(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ehy30d4(v=vs.110).aspx

You can also have a look at [`CellValueChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx), [`CellValueValidated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidated(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`CellEndEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit(v=vs.110).aspx) events.